# Handle utf-8 format posted data

Tags: php, http, utf-8

My c++ desktop application is posting data to my server with the `charset=UTF-8` format (specified in my HTTP request headers). My php script analysing the posted data is not reading `_POST` correctly.

Does my script need to manually decode the posted data? I thought if the HTTP post request specified the charset that the script/php will automatically figure it out?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   $contents .= $key . ", " . $value . "\r\n";
}

// contents = n,  J o h n   D o e 
// when it should = name, John Doe\r\nuserid, hithere\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought if the HTTP post request specified the charset that the script/php will automatically figure it out?

No, character encoding is a lower layer. First of all, you need to let PHP know about the Content-Type of the data that you are sending it.

Check the [manual on $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), it says:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

For HTTP file upload you would use the latter, for other "normal" form data (text fields, anything basically that sends string data) the first one.

And of course your script will have to send the data encoded according to the chosen Content-Type. Whatever HTTP library you are using should provide methods to handle that; I'd recommend a look in the docuentation if you're not sure.

---

That would be the way to do it, as far as emulating HTML forms goes. If that is not your goal, your other option would be to send the data encoded in any format you chose, like f.e. JSON (or maybe even not treated any special way at all), and then read the raw input using `file_get_contents` and the `php://input` stream wrapper.

Comment: My c++ application also specifies the content-type in the header as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The form data is simply `name=John+Doe&userid=hithere`. I've tried `utf8_decode($key)` but no luck, same outcome. Can you point me in the right direction to decode/handle the utf-8 format?

Comment: What does the server log say? Are you sure you are making a POST request?